# How to find IP address of router connected to another router?

Tags: ip, router, lan

I'm trying to setup two routers in my home network, and I'm confused here.

My system looks like this:

[image]

So the router 2 is connected to the line. And I'm (my PC is) connected to router 1. When I type 192.168.1.1, I connect to router 2's config page. So how can I connect to router 1's config page? I tried `ipconfig` in Windows' CMD, but it does not help.

So how can I find the ip of router 1 ?

Note:

192.168.1.2 says Forbidden

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: what is the outpu of `ipconfig`, what is the output of `route print`? Your own IP shold be within the same network adddress range as the address of the first router on your way out (here: router 1) and the default route should point exactly to the first router's address.

Comment: Are you connected to router 2 via wifi? If you have your wifi turned on and you are also connected over ethernet to router 1, your wifi may be taking precedence.  Turn your wireless adapter off.

Comment: It's been a while and I'm not sure whether you ever found an answer for this, but if you're using Windows I just posted an easy GUI solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

As per this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/706645/how-to-find-ip-address-of-my-asus-rt-ac86u-in-access-point-mode):

You may make use of the [ARP](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/arp.htm) command to find the details of your router connected to another router.

1. Connect to your Access Point (or the router 1 in your diagram).
2. Open a Command Prompt.
3. Type in: `arp -a`

The output may look something like this:

`? (192.168.1.1) at 48:f8:b3:36:1a:e8 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.101) at 0:1b:da:29:0:7a on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.138) at a4:5e:60:e5:da:f5 on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.145) at 0:90:a9:dd:a7:d9 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.255) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]`

You may have multiple Interfaces listed, refer to the one that matches the computer's IP address.

- I know 192.168.1.1 is my other main router (router 2 in your diagram).
- In this example, my computer is 192.168.1.138 (can be found out in several ways)
- Addresses ending with .255 can't be the access point as it's the broadcast address for that subnet.

That leaves me with two possibilities.
Looking up my "DHCP client table" in my main router (router 2 in your diagram) configuration, I see 192.168.1.145 as my NAS

So by elimination, 192.168.1.101 is my other router that is acting as an access point.

Answer (score 4):

You are directly connected to Router1, so the corresponding interface's of Router1 is the range of your pc's interface.

For example your pc ip address is 192.168.5.10 and it subnet mask is 255.255.255.0. So connected interface of Router1 is in range 192.168.5.1-254. Just use some tools to scan your LAN to find ip addresses used. In must cases, your pc's default gateway is Router1 IP addresses.

**Edit:**

Tools to scan LAN:

- [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/w/Home)
- [MyLanViewer Network/IP Scanner](http://www.mylanviewer.com/%E2%80%8E)
- [Advanced LAN Scanner](http://www.radmin.com/download/previousversions/lanscanner.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But what tools? Can you please give some examples ?

Comment: And I could really use a resourse that tells what a "subnet mask" is, and what "bridge mode" is.

Comment: @jeff It's called Google ;-) (Or DuckDuckGo - I don't use Google anymore.)

Answer (score 3):

just run a traceroute (traceroute if you're on linux, tracert if windows) to an ip on the other side of router 2

From your diagram it looks like router 2 is connected to the internet, so you could type:

```
traceroute www.google.com
```

You will get output similar to this:

```
traceroute to www.google.co.uk (173.194.78.94), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.1 (192.168.5.1)  0.253 ms  0.247 ms  0.284 ms
 2  lo0-central10.pcl-ag01.blah.net (12.13.14.116)  17.208 ms  18.032 ms  18.029 ms
 3  link-b-central10.pcl-gw02.blah.net (212.159.2.162)  15.656 ms  16.099 ms  16.166 ms
4  194.core.access.blah.net (12.159.0.194)  15.654 ms  16.150 ms  16.077 ms
 5  ae2.pcl-cr01.blah.net (195.166.129.6)  16.388 ms ae1.ptw-cr02.blah.net 
95.166.129.2)  16.385 ms  16.797 ms
 6  ae1.ptw-cr01.blah.net (195.166.129.0)  17.062 ms 72.14.223.32 (172.14.223.32)  15.636 ms  15.977 ms
 7  72.14.222.97 (72.14.222.97)  15.967 ms 209.85.252.186 (209.85.252.186)  14.849 ms  15.273 ms
```

In this instance 192.168.5.1 is my "router 1", your router 2 should appear below this line, and may be your public ip address.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but tracert shows 192.168.1.1, then 10.0.0.5 and continues. Does it recognize the two routers as one router ?

Comment: No, that indicates that 10.0.0.5 should be the internal interface IP of router 2 and 192.168.1.1 the internal interface IP of router 1.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: unless router 2 is in bridge mode.

Comment: @Marki  can a router be in "bridge mode" and still have a modem connected to it? (I have some doubt that it can). And if it wre in bridge mode, if you're suggesting it has no ip, and is just a bridge, how would you explain it having a ip?

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw Try http://10.0.0.5 and see if you get router2's config page.  it may be you didn't configure them right 'cos often you want them on the same subnet (so within the same subnet range).

Comment: This wouldn't work mystery router isn't on the "way out" to WAN (in could be being used a switch to connect a tv, or something)

Comment: @Jonathan, if the router was part  of the route to www.google.com, yes it would. Finding random routers that may or may not be configured correctly is a separate question entirely.

Comment: google.com is what I meant by WAN. There's nothing inherently incorrect in having routers not en route to google, for example finding router 1 from a device hardlined into router 2 in the question diagram

Comment: Assuming the default route on pc[1,2] is router1 AND no other shortest match routes exist on those PCs, then packets MUST traverse router1 to get to router2 and whatever lies beyond. Doing the reverse (from something connected to router2) would just be a matter of tracerouting to pc[1,2] ip address.I doubt security policies allow this however.

Comment: This didn't work for me. @Marki If the router is in bridge mode, which I'm pretty sure I set mine up with, how would you go about finding its IP? I know I've connected via that router's gateway IP before, I just can't remember what it was or I'm remembering right and the old one is no longer working.

Comment: @Hashim. Then your router is (acting as) a switch, and this post is not really relevant to you

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any luck with any of these answers but when I disconnected the second router from the network I was finally able to connect a device with Ethernet and login with the internal IP that was previously only showing the main router config page. I changed the "Operation Mode" from "Router" to "Access Point." Now my secondary router shows up in the list of connected devices and I can see the IP assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above command-line options worked for me, but I was able to successfully find my IP by doing the following from the Windows 7 GUI.

From the Start menu, search for *View network computers and devices*. In the window that opens, look for Router 1's name or brand name. Right-click on it, and click *View device webpage* - this will immediately open the router's gateway address in your browser, with its gateway IP in the address bar.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure you have a smartphone and hopefully its a wireless router. Connect your smartphone to router 1 and then get the connected network's details from your smartphone. You'll end up with the router's IP address.

Otherwise, disconnect router 1 from all connections, inwards and outwards. Then reset the router and it'll use the default IP address that's on the back. If it's the same as router 2, go to "network" and then "LAN settings", and change the IP address. Now reconnect all the cables.

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question. It has some helpful information, but there's no indication that Router 1 is a smartphone in the original question.